# Why did I need to install arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, object, include

I'm very new in Eclipse and still trying to figure it out. I had a project very cluttered and awful looking but a friend started with all the folders and files I need and now I need to fill the files including drivers and everything with what I have already.

The general project he sent me, I can build (and run within Eclipse) it without any error. Now that I have added some drivers (actually C++ files and dependencies) I'm getting errors like:

> make: *** [src/Drivers/SERVO/Dynamixel/dxl_hal.o] Error 127

This particular file (and driver folder) hasn't been changed at all. It was there in the original "general" project and used to be built just ok without any errors, why does it give me this error while I don't even use any functions related to this particular folder?

This is what I get while I have it installed:

> Building file: ../src/Drivers/SERVO/Dynamixel/dxl_hal.c
>
> /bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I installed the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` again and it now works. My problem stays though: why the original project didn't need me to reinstall the arm but the one with added files did? While I didn't use them at all, they were just sitting there in a new folder under src.

Comment: The recent addition says Eclipse cannot find the ARM cross compiler the project uses. It does not look like you have also installed all of the other tools your friend used, or if you have you installed them differently and the provided project is telling Eclipse to look for the tools in the wrong spot.

Comment: Thanks. The original project he has sent works perfectly with no error. I only have added a few .cpp and .h to the project and never used them, but I get this error anyways. So basically the change I have made is adding a couple folders and like 15 files. The fact that the original project gives me no error but this one does is my concern.